# Do you test methods that return queries from the database?

Tags: java, manual-testing, unit-tests, best-practices

I just want to know if you test the output of a query with unit testing. Is this considered good practice?

For example you have a method getUsers()

```
getUsers(){
    // Overly simplified
    return select users from table_users 
           where create_date between "day_a" and "day_b" and active = true
           or where create_date < "day_a" and active = false
}
```

It is a "complex" query and you want to make sure you get a certain output. Maybe you missed something, but not sure if you actually need to create a unit test. Maybe the query should be self explanatory...

I'm looking for opinions.

Comment: The method returns query or query results?

Answer (score 2):

You can't really test the output of a query with unit testing. There are two broad options:

- You could write unit tests that validate the expected value of the query string for given inputs. However, that would be a test of *implementation* rather than *behaviour*; if you came up with a different way of writing the query, even if the overall result was identical, you'd need to rewrite all the tests too. Tests like this actually make it *harder* to improve your code, so don't tend to be valuable. It's also entirely possible that the expected query string *doesn't* end up giving the actual output you want when run against the database, and you don't find that out until later.
- You could *integration* test the output of the query, running it against e.g. an in-memory database for speed and isolation. This verifies the thing that you actually care about, that you get the right output *from the database* for a given input, and gives you the flexibility to refactor the implementation details.

Hopefully it's clear that I'd recommend the second option!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are running this on test data & you have some control over the database or input being used.

Along what jonrsharpe said, what if you seed one or two users that should always return with the query & then validate for them.  No it isn't checking the entire return set, but it is a sanity check that it is not totally broken.

I see value in that, because if the query is totally wrong (I'm assuming the data is used downstream) you need to know that & fix it.  As a downstream tester, knowing that type of unit test would give me a level of confidence in the code that it is ready for me to jump in & start doing some other testing.